# How do i update/change the photosphere/skybox at runtime in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, skybox, photosphere

Something similar to [360 Photo Player VR](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.holumino.vrpano&hl=en)

I want to be able to let the user add and store new photospheres in app but i'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: I'm new to unity, and i've followed and completed [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/building-a-google-cardboard-vr-app-in-unity/) in its entirety so now i would like to add on functionality to it by letting the user add and store new photospheres.

Answer (score 0):

You can change skybox at runtime using [RenderSettings.skybox](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderSettings-skybox.html)

Comment: I'm not sure why, but the skybox is actually attached directly to each camera Left and Right.

GameObject.Find("Main Camera Left").camera.skybox = GameObject.Find("DoubleSidedPhoto.mat");

I'm trying to get this code to work but seems like i'm failing on multiple fronts.

Comment: @DogeLearnsCoding it won't work, because if you use multiple skyboxes in one scene there is a component (Rendering -> Skybox) on your cameras. And you should call it accordingly (GameObject.Find("Main Camera Left").GetComponent<Skybox>().material = ...)

Comment: Thank you. What if i use Inverse Spheres instead? But i'm not sure if i can switch textures in runtime using Inverse Spheres